# Merging rows in my pivot table query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below SQL query is supposed to show a teacher availability. There are 4 possible booking types - AM, PM, Full Day and Hourly. If there's an AM booking, the text in the cell should show PM, if there's a PM booking, it should show AM, if there's a full day booking, or both an AM and a PM booking, it should show 'xxx'. This all works fine.

Now, I move on to the hourly bookings. It is safe to assume there is only ever going to be 2 hourly bookings for each day, 1 for the AM (start time <= 12pm) and 1 for PM (end time > 12pm), meaning we should show 'xxx'. However I am really struggling to get this to show.

```
WITH Bookings AS
(   SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [Status] = CASE 
                            WHEN [3] > 1 THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN ([0] > 0 AND [1] > 0) THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'                            
                            WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) <= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), StartTime) <= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'                           
                        END
    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration, StartTime, EndTime, [x] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays where (Status = 0 or Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(x)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt

             WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 6)

), PivotedBookings AS
(   SELECT  *
    FROM    Bookings
            PIVOT
            (   MAX([Status])
                FOR [WeekDay] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])
            ) pvt

)
SELECT ID,Firstname,Surname,Band,'£' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DefaultChargeRateDaily) + '/' + '£' + CONVERT(varchar(50), DefaultPayRateDaily) as 'BandRates',Telephone,Mobile,Teacher,TeacherAssistant,KeyStage,MAX(Monday) Monday,MAX(Tuesday) Tuesday,MAX(Wednesday) Wednesday,MAX(Thursday) Thursday,MAX(Friday) Friday, Notes
  FROM (
SELECT  t.ID, 
        t.Firstname, 
        t.Surname, 
        tb.Band,
        t.DefaultChargeRateDaily,
        t.DefaultPayRateDaily,
        t.Telephone,
        t.Mobile,
        t.Teacher,
        t.TeacherAssistant,
        CASE WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year7 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y8' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' END + ' - ' + CASE WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' ELSE '' END as 'KeyStage',

        Monday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Monday, '') END,
        Tuesday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 1) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Tuesday, '') END,
        Wednesday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 2) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Wednesday, '') END,
        Thursday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 3) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Thursday, '') END,
        Friday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 4) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Friday, '') END,
        Notes
FROM    Teachers t

        LEFT JOIN PivotedBookings pb
            ON pb.TeacherID = t.ID
        LEFT JOIN TeacherBands tb
            ON tb.ID = t.Band
        LEFT JOIN AvailabilityNotes an 
            ON t.ID = an.TeacherID
            WHERE t.Active = 0 and (t.Status = 1 or t.Status = 0) and t.PrimarySchool = 1
            ) T1
 GROUP BY ID,Firstname,Surname,Telephone,Mobile,Teacher,TeacherAssistant,KeyStage,Notes,DefaultChargeRateDaily,DefaultPayRateDaily,Band
 ORDER BY Surname,Firstname asc
```

The first part generates the following -

```
SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [Status] = CASE 
                            WHEN [3] > 1 THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN ([0] > 0 AND [1] > 0) THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'                            
                            WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) <= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), StartTime) <= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'                           
                        END
    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration, StartTime, EndTime, [x] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays where (Status = 0 or Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(x)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt

             WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'04/22/2013'), 6)
```

Table columns:

```
TeacherID | WeekDay   | Status
9386    Monday      PM
9386    Tuesday     AM
9386    Wednesday   XXX
9763    Monday      PM
9763    Tuesday     AM
9763    Wednesday   XXX
9927    Monday      PM
9927    Tuesday     AM
9927    Wednesday   XXX
10358   Monday      PM
10358   Monday      AM
```

We can see here, the last 2 rows need merging and showing in the status column as XXX.

An example is shown in the screenshot below. Highlighted yellow, it is showing PM. However, there is 2 hourly bookings (BookingDuration ID 3), one 10:00am - 11:00am and another 14:00 - 15:00. THerefore, this should show XXX, rather than PM/AM.

[image: Screenshot]

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do, can you edit your post with table structures, sample data and then the desired result of the query?

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. I have added a screenshot simply because I have ran out of time for today. If needed, sample data can be posted tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be traced back to the first query:

```
FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration, StartTime, EndTime, [x] = 1
            FROM    BookingDays 
            WHERE   (Status = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
        ) BookingDays
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(x)
            FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
        ) pvt
```

The idea of this was to get an ouput where there was one row per day per teacher, with the addition of `StartTime` and `EndTime` to the subquery it is not guaranteed that you will get one row per teacher per day, because two records may have different start/end times for the same date, to get around this you could use:

```
| TeacherID | BookingDate | BookingDuration | StartTime | EndTime |
|-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+---------|
|    1      |  20130422   |        3        |   10:00   |  11:00  |
|    1      |  20130422   |        3        |   13:00   |  14:00  |
```

In the booking CTE this would return (if you added start/endtime to select list, but removing them would not make it one row):

```
| TeacherID | WeekDay | Status | StartTime | EndTime |
|-----------+---------|--------+-----------+---------|
|    1      |  Monday |   'AM' |   10:00   |  11:00  |
|    1      |  Monday |   'PM' |   13:00   |  14:00  |
```

If you used the following

```
FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, 
                    BookingDate, 
                    BookingDuration, 
                    StartTime = MIN(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate),
                    EndTime = MIN(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate)
                    [x] = 1
            FROM    BookingDays 
            WHERE   (Status = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
        ) BookingDays
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(x)
            FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
        ) pvt
```

Using windowed functions you can ensure only the same StartTime and EndTime will be returned per Teacher/day combination you would get:

```
| TeacherID | WeekDay | Status | StartTime | EndTime |
|-----------+---------|--------+-----------+---------|
|    1      |  Monday |  'XXX' |   10:00   |  14:00  |
```

You would then not need to merge the rows later on in your query.

Another change you need to make is to change the CASE Statement in for `Status` slightly, so you get a full query as:

```
WITH Bookings AS
(   SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [Status] = CASE 
                            WHEN ([0] > 0 AND [1] > 0) THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'                            
                            WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND EndTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'   
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND EndTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'                        
                        END
    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, 
                        BookingDate, 
                        BookingDuration, 
                        StartTime = CAST(MIN(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME),
                        EndTime = CAST(MAX(EndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME),
                        [x] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays 
                WHERE   (Status = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(x)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt
)
```

All I have done here is remove the line `WHEN [3] > 1`, just in case there could be two hourly slots both occurring in the AM, or both in the PM (I know you has said it is safe to assume this won't happen but for completeness I have added it), and I have moved the following line higher up:

```
WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND EndTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'
```

This should be all the changes that are required to get the data in the format you require.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed172/3) (Note teacher 5)**

**EDIT**

As you have said, if there is an hourly slot in the morning and an afternoon slot, or the other way round, the above will fail. I think if you change your case statement to the below this should get around the problem.

```
        [Status] = CASE 
                        WHEN ([0] > 0 AND [1] > 0) THEN 'XXX'
                        WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'    
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND EndTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX' 
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND [1] > 0 THEN 'XXX'          
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND [0] > 0 THEN 'XXX'
                        WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                        WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'  
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND EndTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'                        
                    END
```

Comment: once again, genius! Thanks again!